# Automatically download TeamCity build artifacts once build is complete

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, teamcity

is it possible to set the TeamCity Eclipse plug-in to automatically download build artifacts once the build is complete?  I've been looking, but can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Looks like this is destined to become a tumbleweed. In case anyone else is looking for this, the best solution I've found is to ask the TeamCity admin to make the build artifacts available on a shared network drive. You can then write a script to download all artifacts to the appropriate locations. If sufficiently motivated, you can even poll the artifact directory periodically for new files, so that you don't have to run the script manually.

Answer (score 0):

Ahar but from the tumbleweed comes an anwser... but it unfortunately doesn't involve the eclipse plugin

1. You need to install an additional agent on your development machine/the machine you want the artifacts deployed to.
2. Create a new Build that is empty/does nothing, (ie create the build and save/cancel it as soon as you have created it, don't even add a Source Control connection)
3. Add an Artifact Dependency to the Build, this is in the Dependancies part of the Build.  An artifact dependency tells an agent to pull in an artifact from a different Build.  You choose the Build you want the artifact to be pulled in from, you specify an artifact (which can include an wildcard), and you choose a destination folder to where you want the files downloaded to/extracted.
4. Add a Build Trigger, make this Build trigger where your main build succeeds, ie you have an artifact to download.
5. Add an Agent Requirement, teamcity.agent.name is the name of the agent running on your development machine/deployment machine...

Summary, when your primary Build succeeds, teamcity will fire off this secondary Build on the agent running on your deployment machine/development machine which pulls in the artifact(s) and unzips them to the correct location, (and if you want runs additional commands such as installing a database)

This works really well for automated deployments of test servers, the only disadvantage to this method is you use up a Build Agent Licence and Build for every machine you want to do this on.  But the advantage of automated deployment to remote machine outweighs the disadvantage.